# Oracle to SQL Server syntax change

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

I'm having some problems with the following query:

```
select * from
(
  select inventory.location, inventory.itemnum as itemnum, item.description as itemdesc,
  inventory.minlevel as olevel , invcost.avgcost from inventory join invcost on inventory.itemnum = invcost.itemnum join item on inventory.itemnum = item.itemnum
  where inventory.location = 'KHSTORE' AND inventory.itemnum BETWEEN '1221' and '1221' and invcost.location = 'KHSTORE'
) table1
  join
  (select SUM(balvalues) as balance, itemnum from
    (select ib.CURBAL as balvalues, inventory.itemnum as itemnum from invbalances ib join inventory on ib.itemnum = inventory.itemnum and ib.location = inventory.location where inventory.itemnum BETWEEN '1221' and '1221'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  SUM(-1*QUANTITY) , itemnum from matrectrans where itemnum BETWEEN '1221' and '1221' and TRANSDATE >= '05-MAY-2015' and tostoreloc = 'KHSTORE' group by itemnum
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  SUM(-1*QUANTITY) , itemnum from matusetrans where itemnum BETWEEN '1221' and '1221' and TRANSDATE >= '05-MAY-2015' and storeloc = 'KHSTORE' group by itemnum
    )group by itemnum
  ) table2 on table1.itemnum = table2.itemnum;
```

The query runs fine on an Oracle database but when I try to run the same on an SQL Server instance I get the following error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.
```

I'm looking for a way to change this query and make it compatible with both Orace and SQLS, or if not then at least make it run on SQL Server

Comment: Unrelated, but: if `itemnum` is a number, then you shouldn't compare it to a string ("apples and oranges"). `1221` is a number, `'1221'` is a string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add alias to subquery:

```
select * from
(
  select inventory.location, inventory.itemnum as itemnum, item.description as itemdesc,
  inventory.minlevel as olevel , invcost.avgcost from inventory join invcost on inventory.itemnum = invcost.itemnum join item on inventory.itemnum = item.itemnum
  where inventory.location = 'KHSTORE' AND inventory.itemnum BETWEEN '1221' and '1221' and invcost.location = 'KHSTORE'
) table1
  join
  (select SUM(balvalues) as balance, itemnum from
    (select ib.CURBAL as balvalues, inventory.itemnum as itemnum from invbalances ib join inventory on ib.itemnum = inventory.itemnum and ib.location = inventory.location where inventory.itemnum BETWEEN '1221' and '1221'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  SUM(-1*QUANTITY) , itemnum from matrectrans where itemnum BETWEEN '1221' and '1221' and TRANSDATE >= '05-MAY-2015' and tostoreloc = 'KHSTORE' group by itemnum
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  SUM(-1*QUANTITY) , itemnum from matusetrans where itemnum BETWEEN '1221' and '1221' and TRANSDATE >= '05-MAY-2015' and storeloc = 'KHSTORE' group by itemnum
    ) AS t  /* HERE */
  group by itemnum
  ) table2 on table1.itemnum = table2.itemnum;
```

Using CTE for more readability:

```
WITH table1 AS 
(
  SELECT  inventory.location, inventory.itemnum as itemnum, item.description as itemdesc,
  inventory.minlevel as olevel , invcost.avgcost
  FROM inventory
  JOIN invcost
    ON inventory.itemnum = invcost.itemnum
  JOIN item
    ON inventory.itemnum = item.itemnum
  WHERE inventory.location = 'KHSTORE'
      AND inventory.itemnum BETWEEN '1221' and '1221'
      AND invcost.location = 'KHSTORE'
),
 table2 AS
(
 SELECT SUM(balvalues) as balance,itemnum
 FROM
    (SELECT ib.CURBAL as balvalues, inventory.itemnum as itemnum
     FROM invbalances ib
     JOIN inventory 
       ON ib.itemnum = inventory.itemnum
       AND ib.location = inventory.location
     WHERE inventory.itemnum BETWEEN '1221' AND '1221'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  SUM(-1*QUANTITY) , itemnum
    FROM matrectrans
    WHERE itemnum BETWEEN '1221' AND '1221'
       AND TRANSDATE >= '05-MAY-2015'
       AND tostoreloc = 'KHSTORE'
    GROUP BY itemnum
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  SUM(-1*QUANTITY) , itemnum
    FROM matusetrans
    WHERE itemnum BETWEEN '1221' AND '1221'
       AND TRANSDATE >= '05-MAY-2015'
       AND storeloc = 'KHSTORE'
    GROUP BY itemnum
    ) AS t   /* HERE */
  GROUP BY itemnum
)
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2
 ON table2 on table1.itemnum = table2.itemnum;
```

**EDIT**

Using CTE no subqueries

```
WITH table1 AS 
    (
      SELECT  inventory.location, inventory.itemnum as itemnum, item.description as itemdesc,
      inventory.minlevel as olevel , invcost.avgcost
      FROM inventory
      JOIN invcost
        ON inventory.itemnum = invcost.itemnum
      JOIN item
        ON inventory.itemnum = item.itemnum
      WHERE inventory.location = 'KHSTORE'
          AND inventory.itemnum BETWEEN '1221' and '1221'
          AND invcost.location = 'KHSTORE'
    )
    ,table2_helper AS
    (
         SELECT ib.CURBAL as balvalues, inventory.itemnum as itemnum
         FROM invbalances ib
         JOIN inventory 
           ON ib.itemnum = inventory.itemnum
           AND ib.location = inventory.location
         WHERE inventory.itemnum BETWEEN '1221' AND '1221'
         UNION ALL
         SELECT  SUM(-1*QUANTITY) , itemnum
         FROM matrectrans
         WHERE itemnum BETWEEN '1221' AND '1221'
           AND TRANSDATE >= '05-MAY-2015'
           AND tostoreloc = 'KHSTORE'
         GROUP BY itemnum
         UNION ALL
         SELECT  SUM(-1*QUANTITY) , itemnum
         FROM matusetrans
         WHERE itemnum BETWEEN '1221' AND '1221'
           AND TRANSDATE >= '05-MAY-2015'
           AND storeloc = 'KHSTORE'
         GROUP BY itemnum
    )
     ,table2 AS
    (
     SELECT SUM(balvalues) as balance,itemnum
     FROM table2_helper
     GROUP BY itemnum
    )
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2
     ON table2 on table1.itemnum = table2.itemnum;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. So is there no unified query that can run on both systems?

Comment: @AuthenticReplica There should be as both support ANSI standard but as you see every DB has own syntax. Does solution with `WITH` not work on Oracle? I can make one more step in CTE and get rid of subquery when you union all.